# PIVOT table mysql with data from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, pivot, pivot-table

I have a school management system, this system has to analyze data, especially student marks.

I want to be able to show student performance, in the following way;

1. Show a table that shows the students marks per subject as well as the student average mark and position.

Example

```
Position | Class | Student Average | Student Name  | Geography | History | Biology | English | Math |
 10        Grade11       57%          John Doe          59%        40%         66%      48%     56%
 11        Grade11       56%          John Smith        53%        33%         56%      68%     26%
 12        Grade11       55%          Paul Doe          29%        30%         46%      38%     36%
```

This is the code I am using and it is not displaying the marks like above

```
SELECT
    marks.student_id,
    subjects.subject_name,
    ROUND(AVG(mark)) AS mark
FROM
    marks
INNER JOIN teaching_loads ON teaching_loads.id = marks.teaching_load_id
INNER JOIN subjects ON subjects.id = teaching_loads.subject_id
INNER JOIN grades ON grades.id=teaching_loads.class_id

WHERE
    grades.stream_id = 5 AND marks.assessement_id = 1
GROUP BY
    subject_id, marks.student_id
```

**Result of above query is**

[image: Result of Query]

The system has the following tables

**Marks Table**-This is the table that stores student marks

```
CREATE TABLE `marks` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `teacher_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `student_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `teaching_load_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `assessement_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `mark` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Teaching Loads Table**
This table is where we store the subject the teacher is teaching and in which class he/she is teaching that subject.

```
CREATE TABLE `teaching_loads` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `teacher_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `subject_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `class_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `session_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Subjects Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `subjects` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `subject_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `subject_type` enum('core','elective','non-value','passing_subject') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Users Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `middlename` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a students table? I assume that's where student name and class come from?

Comment: @DonR the name, student_id is stored in the users table. student_id is a  foreign key in the marks, it references the id in Users table

Comment: please make a complete [mre]

Comment: But consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Also tables in relational databases normally have primary keys

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to join the **marks**, **teaching_loads**, and **subjects** tables multiple times, once for each subject, and calculate the row average on each row (The **AVG** aggregate function calculates a value across rows for the specified column). Here's an example with the first two subjects to show what I mean (this assumes all subjects for a given student are the same class):

```
SELECT
    geog_load.class_id
    ,(geog.mark + hist.mark) / 2
    ,student.name || ' ' || student.lastname
    ,geog.mark
    ,hist.mark
FROM
    users AS student
    INNER JOIN marks AS geog ON geog.student_id = student.id
    INNER JOIN teaching_loads AS geog_load ON geog_load.id = geog.teaching_load_id
    INNER JOIN
        subjects as geog_subject ON geog_subject.id = geog_load.subject_id
        AND geog_subject.subject_name = 'Geography'
    INNER JOIN marks AS hist ON hist.student_id = student.id
    INNER JOIN teaching_loads AS hist_load ON hist_load.id = hist.teaching_load_id
    INNER JOIN
        subjects as hist_subject ON hist_subject.id = hist_load.subject_id
        AND hist_subject.subject_name = 'History'
```

Then you can filter how you like with a **WHERE** clause, and use **RANK()** to show **Position** numbers, or whatever.